# How to find the volume and outermost point of each dimension of a multidimensional polyhedron?

Tags: geometry, volume, polyhedra

I have D-dimensional polyhedrons of the form

$ \Sigma _{i=1}^{D} \frac{|x_i-c_i|}{b_i}=\gamma$ with $c_i$,$b_i$ and $\gamma$ as (fixed) values and $x$ as a variable.

I need to find the volume of these polyhedrons as well as the outermost points in each dimension to see if the polyhedrons exceed the feasible limits of my problem. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks for your time.